# Docker, communicating between hosts on different bridges

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My case:

- I have a container (container_A) on the default bridge network (172.17.0.1/16)
- I have a group of containers -- created through docker-compose -- on another bridge (172.18.0.1/16). One of them is named container_B_1 (ip: 172.18.0.2)

By default, I cannot ping from container_A to container_B_1

The question: how to make that particular container (container_B_1) accessible as well from the default bridge network? In other words: to let it have 172.17.0.x IP (beside the 172.18.0.x IP). Just that one container.

I've tried this in my docker-compose.yml

[image]

But, gettting error: "Network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks"

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own network and specify it in your compose file:

- Create your own network:

  `docker network create --driver bridge my_dev_network`

  you could verify by `docker network ls`
- In your docker-compose.yml for the two containers (container A) and the other group of containers, specify the network you just created:

[image: network]

you could verify by `docker network inspect my_dev_network` to see if all the containers have joined your own network

Answer (score 2):

To keep the same IP series, I was having the same issue, and found this solution.

Include 
`network_mode: bridge`
under each service in your compose file.

This way you do not have to create a custom network.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3012

From ninchan8328 commented on May 16, 2016:

> I figured out, i can have the docker-compose to start the container in a custom network and then do a docker network connect bridge [container] to join the default network that way.